# Project "Ball on Plate" (touchscreen connection)

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, touchscreen

I'm working on a project "Ball on Plate".
Now, I do have this touchscreen: https://de.rs-online.com/web/p/touchscreen-sensoren/7105240/, which I have to connect with my raspberry pi 4. I need to know which coordinates are given, when I touch the display on several points.

My problem is, I don't know how to connect that display with my raspberry pi and further how to display the coordinate values on my monitor.

ps. most "Ball on Plate" projects were made with an Arduino, do you think that I'm using the wrong device ? Which pro's and contras would I have if choose a raspberry and which with an arduino ?

Thank you in anticipation !

Comment: Raspberry Pi is not a microcontroller. It runs with an operating system and it can be considered as a PC.

Comment: Try reading the datasheet for your part.  Also, this isn't a "hey let's talk about tips and ideas" round table.  Ask a specific question, get a good answer.  And pros and cons are often opinions.  So do your own research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a resistive touch panel, where you have to select the direction with digital pins and read the resulting voltage with an  analog-digital-converter (ADC). An Arduino has it built-in, but the raspberry pi does not have this built-in. If you want to use the raspberry pi, you need an additional ADC, that you connect to the raspberry pi.

Here you can find some more information how you could do it with an arduino: https://www.instructables.com/Resistive-Touch-Screen-on-the-DP32/

Comment: Thank you very much ! But do you also have any idea, if its a good idea to use a raspberry pi for this project? Or, am I going to make everything more complicated.           Which one would you prefer ?

Comment: I am not very familiar with raspberry pi, so I can not give you a good answer to that. But in general, if you dont know what how to start, start by copying others that already did something similar.